# Saving core data results in a crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a problem with my core data. I am trying to save the context and I keep getting this error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

This is my code where I make the core data things:

```
managedObjectModel_ = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSBundle mainBundle]]];

persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel_];

managedObjectContext_ = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[managedObjectContext_ setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator_];
```

I really have no idea what's going on.
BTW, I am developing for iOS if it makes a difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add persistent store to coordinator. Something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self applicationDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabaseName.sqlite"]];

NSError *error;
if (![storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSAssert1(NO, @"Adding of store to coordinator faild. %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Lets see if it works that way. Edit: Tried it that way but it doesn't work. BTW I am developing for iOS.

Comment: @Samuli Lehtonen, You have same error message? This code need to add right after `persistentStoreCoordinator_` alloc/init.